# AH00052: child pid 2453 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: java, php, mysql, apache, server

I am using apache 2.4 on fedora and when i am trying to open my page, it is showing completely blank. I checked the apache logs, there are many lines showing `([core:notice] [pid 1483] AH00052: child pid 1486 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)).`

I have no idea what is causing this error and getting blank page is because of this only or not.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Segfaults are serious native errors. You've got some buggy component that you should probably update.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman, but if i change the extension from .php to .html, it is working finr, obviously php code is not working but page is displaying properly.

Comment: I also checked on Firefox developers tool, i can see this " [HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required 4ms]" in console.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on a server configured to require client certificates to grant access to the site. The cause was an expired CRL, and installing a new CRL fixed the issue.

The reason becomes apparent by increasing the log level for the relevant vhost to `info`. By default it only logs `error` or worse, which only produces a cryptic message about failure to re-negotiate a handshake.